# How to describe rules in a request body using swagger?

Tags: php, laravel, swagger, documentation

So i'm writting a documentation for an Laravel API and i want to describe some rules for that my request is going to validate. By now, i'm writting the rules in the description field, but it just doesn't seem that right... is there a better way to do it??
Example:

```
 *      @OA\Parameter (
 *          name="buying_cost",
 *          in="path",
 *          description="Additional item's buying cost
 *                      must be less or equal than selling cost
 *                      must be sent in cents",
 *          required=true,
 *          example="50000"
 *      ),
```

Comment: Is this about Swagger or l5-swagger? https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger

Comment: I'm working with l5-swagger